# PowerBuilder 11: Programmatically adding a DataWindow to a control

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

Anyone have the slightest clue on how I can pro grammatically instantiate and add a DataWindow control to an object?  Sybase's online doc is horrible.  TIA.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It's not very common to to create DataWindow controls at runtime. There may be an easier way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to create a standard visual user object of type DataWindow (something you're hopefully using already... many benefits) and use OpenUserObject() or OpenUserObjectWithParm().

Good luck,

Terry.